# Javascript - How can I get the thumbnails of a YouTube video (the one that shows when you hover to slider)?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, thumbnails, youtube-javascript-api

I am creating a custom slider for a YouTube video, and currently using the javascript player API.

How can I get those thumbnails when you hover to slider? or is there any way to do it?

Edit:

What I need is the thumbnails that you can see when seeking through the video. This is also visible as a sprite when you try to create a video clip from one of your uploaded video. But you need to login/authenticate for that..

Answer (score 0):

you can use ffmpeg to get the thumbnail of video.
Below is the link for how to use ffmpeg in C#

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/111468/FFmpeg-Tutorial

Comment: Nice suggestion, but in my situation, I just need to get the thumbnails from YouTube itself, just like any other YouTube APIs functions. So I can use it on the go.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [queuing functions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Queueing_Functions), according to specs cueVideoById function should load the specified video's thumbnail and prepares the player to play the video, and does not load the video.

Comment: I scan through the API, but I think I can only get the video's default thumbnail..

What I need is the thumbnails that you can see when seeking through the video. This is also visible as a sprite when you try to create a video clip from one of your uploaded video. But you need to login/authenticate for that..

Comment: with the startSeconds parameter i think it should load the desired frame